# How can I go through a dictionary of line separated words one word at a time in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 10,000 words that I would like to be able to go through one at a time using a for loop.  In the dictionary .txt file, each word is on a new line.  How would I import the .txt file and isolate each word to perform operations on?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I would recommend starting with a good Python tutorial

Comment: [Here you go](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). In particular, check out the line starting with "For reading lines from a file..."

Comment: Give an example of your text file.

Comment: You don't seem to have made any effort to solve this yourself. We're happy to help with problems in code you've written, but you at least need to have a go first.

Comment: Dictionary is a data structure method in python, so your question is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the help.  As you can probably tell, this is my first big python project ever.  @thefourtheye thanks for the tutorial link, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting with something like this:

```
# open the text file and iterate line by line
with open(myTextFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        # do something with the content in each line
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading up on how to read files in python I ended up using that exact same code snippet.

Comment: @electriccello If his answer helped you then upvote it and accept the answer :)